# Azure CLI - run a script file

Tags: azure, azure-cli

What is the process for running a set of AZ commands contained in a file?  What should the file extension be?  For example, the following commands are contained in a file called 'sample.ps1'.

```
az login --subscription "demo-sub1"

az group create \

    --name "demo-rg" \

    --location "West US 2"
```

Is there an AZ command to run from within Powershell that will load/run this file?  .\sample.ps1 does not seem to work as expected.  The login prompt is displayed, but when I pick the account to log in to, nothing happens, the "Pick an Account" screen stays up, whereas normally just running the az login command from PS would work, then redirect.  In this case it just hangs and the second line of the script never gets executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case - powershell is just a shell. for example, the following works just fine inside the sample.ps1:

```
az login
az group list
```

the only caveat - powershell uses backtick as a line continuation character, not `\`. so your code should look like this:

```
az login --subscription "demo-sub1"
az group create `
    --name "demo-rg" `
    --location "West US 2"
```

Comment: Using the backtick also corrected the issue of the script hanging on the logon prompt in the browser.  The script now runs properly.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should use a `*.cmd` file if you wanna script azureCli. Hence your file would look like this

```
@echo off

az login --subscription "demo-sub1"

az group create \

    --name "demo-rg" \

    --location "West US 2"
```

If you wanna use PowerShell then would suggest using Azure PowerShell.
Also if you're using a script to log in, I would suggest you use a service principal.

```
@echo off

az login --service-principal --username APP_ID --tenant TENANT_ID --password /path/to/cer
```

The documentation is a bit off when it comes to key vault but the rest is correct

check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: why? there is no benefit in using `.cmd` file whatsoever

Comment: I am not a big fan of either but with regards to the question of "what should the file extension be?" *.cmd would be the case.
But I would even suggest he using Azure PowerShell and write everything in PowerShell

Comment: why? if the intention is to run in powershell, like the question mentions. why would you suggest a person looking to run az cli to use azure powershell?

Comment: Sorry if I caused some confusion with my question...still learning all this...my question basically amounts to, how do I run a group of AZ commands contained in a file?  I was under the impression that the az cli is an extension of Powershell, and that it is initiated with the 'az'.  Maybe I need to better understand the distinction between Powershell, Azure Powershell, and Azure CLI.

Comment: azure cli is just a binary file, you can call it from anywhere. (it is available in linux, windows, macos).